# Ошибка Strict Standards в PHP

Tags: php

Привет всем, есть вот такая функция на PHP:

```
function getFieldLevel($vid, $field) {
        $q = "SELECT f" . $field . " FROM tx5_fdata WHERE vref = $vid";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $q);
        return array_shift($result->fetch_row()); // Ошибку вызывает вот этот код
    }
```

Но этот код приводит к такой ошибке:

**Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 1536**

Как справиться с ошибкой? Поможет ли функция <code>is_numeric()</code>?

Comment: Предыдущий комментарий не в тему был, поэтому:

    return array_shift($result->fetch_all());

Comment: Нет, тут дело не в этом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$row = $result->fetch_row();
return array_shift($row);
```

Вот тогда ошибка исчезает!

Comment: все верно. В ошибке написано, что в array_shift() нужно передавать заранее инициализированную переменную с результатом